# Java,GUI: Checking if input is even or not

Tags: java, user-interface

I am making a GUI program using Java, to check if the user's input is even or not(integer). I tried Integer.parseInt() but that did not work. A lot of errors show up when I try to input a number(I am able to open the GUI).

The code:

```
package kip;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Kip2 extends JFrame {
    private JTextField one;
    private JTextField two;
    int number;
    String text;

    public Kip2(){
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        one = new JTextField(10);
        text = one.getText();
        add(one);
        two = new JTextField("Enter a number: ");
        two.setEditable(false);
        add(two);

        hand handler = new hand();
        one.addActionListener(handler);
        two.addActionListener(handler);
    }
    public class hand implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String msg = "";
            if (event.getSource()==one)
                number = Integer.parseInt(text);
                if (number%2==0)
                    msg = msg.format("%s is even!", one);
                else
                    msg = msg.format("%s is not even!", one);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error(which I do not really understand):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at kip.Kip2$hand.actionPerformed(Kip2.java:30)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at kip.Kip2$hand.actionPerformed(Kip2.java:30)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I dont understand "Checking if input is even or not" and in the question you ask about receive an integer from a gui..

Answer (score 2):

you should set `String text` from `textfield` value  just before event get fired.

like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String msg = "";
            text=one.getText(); // add this line // set value of String text to value of one textfield when event fire
```

you are currently set `String text` from text field when GUI starts.so when  gui starts there is no text but a empty `String` .you get error when try to convert empty String to a integer.

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" 
                                                     ^
                                                  empty String
```

and also you may need to use

```
 msg = msg.format("%s is even!", text); // same for odd line
```

instead of

```
 msg = msg.format("%s is even!", one);
```

if you print one it will show the source of one textfield.

here is [complete code](http://pastebin.com/BdN8YSiL)